# CSRF Java libraries

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

I was wondering what libraries are out there regarding protecting J2EE applications against CSRF attacks.

I have used CSRF Guard by OWASP.  I tried searching but couldn't find any other production quality libraries.  Are there any others?

On a side note, the application I'm building is using the Grails framework so if there are Grail's CSRF plugins, I would like to know as well.

Answer (score 0):

New into CSRF but I'm using Grails and for any forms I'm using this method to prevent duplicate form posts, but it would prevent CSRF attacks as well?

```
<g:form method="post" useToken="true">
```

And then

```
withForm {
   // good request
}.invalidToken {
   // bad request
}
```

Comment: According to OWASP and Grails documentation, solving the duplicate posts with synchronizer tokens also protects against CSRF, provided your application is not vulnerable to XSS... https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet and https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/html5/#csrf